# Authorization Header not getting displayed in CURL springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I am using the `springdoc-openapi-ui`. I have configured the global headers named `Authorization`.
When I execute the API `Authorization` is not showing in the CURL of the requests. My other parameters are showing in the CURL except `Authorization`.

Previously, I was using the `springfox-swagger-ui` and that time it was showing in CURL section.

I have searched for the same and found Note on https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters
`Note: Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed.`

But my requirement to use `Authorization` as header only. Is there any away we can achieve this?

My `SwaggerConfiguration` is added below.

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Value("${title:title}")
    private String title;
    @Value("${description:description.}")
    private String description;
    @Value("${version:0.0.1}")
    private String version;

    @Value("${schemeId}")
    String schemeIdentifier;

    @Bean
    public OperationCustomizer customGlobalHeaders() {

        return (Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) -> {

            Parameter authorization = new Parameter().in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString()).name("Authorization")
                    .description("Authorization details JWT token")
                    .schema(new StringSchema()).required(true);

            Parameter applicationId = new Parameter().in(ParameterIn.HEADER.toString()).schema(new StringSchema())
                    .name("Application-Id").description("Originating application or client using the service")
                    .required(false);

            operation.addParametersItem(authorization);
            operation.addParametersItem(applicationId);

            return operation;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public GroupedOpenApi adminApi() {      

        String[] packagesToscan = { "abc.controller" };

        return GroupedOpenApi.builder().setGroup("Client").packagesToScan(packagesToscan).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title(title).version(version).description(description))
                .components(new Components());
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use annotations that would generate `securitySchemes` + `security` (if you use OpenAPI 3.0) or `securityDefinitions` + `security` (in OpenAPI 2.0) - that's how the `Authorization` header is defined.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I got your point.
I have 300+ https methods so for each method I need to use annotations and this is quite time consuming. I am looking for generic solutions if any.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have searched for an answer on the same.
We can not set Authorization as a header with `springdoc open api`. if we want to use then we need to enable the authorization button on `swagger ui`.

[image]

then it will shows in CURL section as shown below.

[image]

code to enable authorization button on swagger in glabal location

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new 
             Info().title("title").version("version").description("description"))
                .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList("my security"))
                .components(new Components().addSecuritySchemes("my security",
                        new SecurityScheme().name("my 
                 security").type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer")));
    }
}
```