# X-Forwarded-For does not appear when I click" Try it out" in swagger-ui.html

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a sample github using springdoc : https://github.com/vmisra2018/sb-example-swaggerdoc
and I can't figure out how can I enable X-Forwarded-For for any api eg:" /person " when i click try-it-out

**To Reproduce**
Steps to reproduce the behavior:

version of spring-boot=> 2.2.2.RELEASE

modules and versions of springdoc-openapi =>springdoc-openapi-ui:1.2.32

I have below entry as per https://springdoc.org/faq.html and also defined ForwardedHeaderFilter bean,

```
server:
    forward-headers-strategy: NATIVE
```

Sample code:
https://github.com/vmisra2018/sb-example-swaggerdoc

**Expected behavior**
I want to see X-Forwarded-For header when i click try-it-out in swagger-ui.html. I dont see it.

Answer (score 0):

It was just a matter of adding parameter. I got hint from here :
[Authorization Header not getting displayed in CURL springdoc-openapi-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208100/authorization-header-not-getting-displayed-in-curl-springdoc-openapi-ui)

Documentation is confusing for a new person. The one that is explained in faq is for enabling x-forwarded-for but iis it for swagger-ui? The purpose of swaggerui plugin for me was to display api and be able to test ap and I simply wanted to pass x-forwarded-for from swagger-ui and I kept on searching for it.
Solution is in  fix-xforwardedfor-swaggerdoc branch
[github](https://github.com/vmisra2018/sb-example-swaggerdoc/tree/fix-xforwardedfor-swaggerdoc)

Answer (score 0):

X-Forwarded-For is set by web servers in general ...
If your application exposes this Header it can be avaialble on the swagger-ui without any issue.

For the Authorization Header the cause is different, The OpenAPI 3 specification does not allow explicitly adding Authorization header. For more information, please read:

Note: Header parameters named Accept, Content-Type and Authorization are not allowed. To describe these headers

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#header-parameters.

Comment: well the case is it is passed by client calling service/application (which you can assume the sample). For this swaager-ui wont expose it unless you do it the way i did. you can check out sample from  my github and if you provide a fix ,I will accept the answer in that case.